# Git: Are MERGING master into feature branch and REBASING feature branch on master equivalent?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

Does `merging` *master* into a *feature branch* and `rebasing` *feature branch* on *master* have same end result in every possible situation, or should I favor one or other in a specific context and why? I know merging creates additional commit for better history comprehension, but I'm more interested in the actual outcome of an operation and it's probability to succeed. So is there an actual difference, or could I choose either approach based on convention (or even use them both inclusive)?

Also, how often should I need to sync `feature branch` with `master`? Is it a good practice to `merge/rebase` every time I return to develop a specific feature, or should I keep the feature isolated from the rest of the architecture for as long as possible?

How to scope with situation when multiple features are highly dependent of each other? Should the features be developed as a single feature branch, or as a distinct feature branches merged to public feature branch? Lets say, in `Spring framework`, many configurations and layers are dependent of each other. What is the common workflow to keep it all whole and sync?

Answer (score 2):

Both merging and rebasing solve the same problem in a very different way. Unlike rebasing, merging is non-destructive. However, as long as you follow the Golden Rule of Rebasing, everything will work fine, and you can enjoy having a neat commit history. The rule is "don't use rebasing with public branches."

> Also, how often should I need to sync feature branch with master?

This is mostly a matter of taste. As explained in [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), there are different Branching Workflows that one can choose from.

Comment: I'm still little concerned about `rebase` dangers. What happens if I `rebase` local branch on *unpublished* commits of `master`, at this point publish the branch and later decide to reset `master` to `origin/master`. Now if somebody merges that branch with `master`, it will be a big mess right? Could one golden rule be, only rebase on published commits.

Comment: Also, is it safe to `rebase` a branch which is merged to master, and for some reason continued working on later?

Comment: One common practice is to have parallel long-running branches, like master and develop, where master is the most stable branch. Then, you mainly work with the develop branch by creating short-lived topic branches and merging/rebasing often. Once you are confident about your work, you merge/rebase with the master. You can read more about this in [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Answer (score 1):

Rebasing and merging are not equal in all situations as when you rebase on master you are actually make new commits on top of master, which will have a different id and contents. This is why it is important to not rebase public branches. However, rebasing can give you a nice clean history.

As for the branch section of the question: it appears that what you are looking for is a branching model. One of the most popular branching model is git flow which uses a merge model.

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

The essence of the git flow model is the use of master, release, develop, and feature branches (among others) to organise the state that your code is in. With this model it should be easy to tell when to merge, as it will be at certain stages, for example: a feature is complete or you are going to do your next release.

Comment: This still didn't answer my question, if it makes sense to `merge` `develop` branch to `feature` branch every now and then. Is it a good convention to keep `feature` isolated from rest of the infrastructure for as long as possible, and `merge` or `rebase` only if dependencies dictates so? And same dilemma with multiple dependent public `feature` branches: is it acceptable to merge them with each other, or first merge to develop? I'm probably overthinking this, but I want to get the whole clear picture.

Comment: This is completely up to you. You only *need* to merge develop into feature when you have some change (like a new feature) in develop that your feature branch needs.

Comment: IMO I would merge develop into feature regularly if the feature branch is modifying code that might clash with another change, thus making it easier to resolve conflicts incrementally.